# How to get the count of records on each date in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have several records on the mongoDB. I need to know the no of records present on each date.I know that we can get the date from _id field.Please help me how to do this ?

Comment: What is your document scructure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [MongoDB Map-Reduce feature](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce), using [`ObjectID::getTimestamp()` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#gettimestamp) to determine insertion time.

Here is an example of doing so:

```js
db.runCommand({
  mapreduce: 'collection',
  map: function() {
    var created = this._id.getTimestamp();
    var date = created.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    return emit(date, 1);
  },
  reduce: function(key, vals) {
    return Array.sum(vals);
  },
  out: {
    inline: 1
  }
})
```

I'm using [`Date::toISOString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to convert insertion date into ISO date string

```
2014-07-21T12:39:21.000Z
```

and [`String::slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to take first 10 characters of it

```
2014-07-21
```

The resulting output of this Map-Reduce task should look like this:

```js
[
  {
    "_id" : "2014-07-21", // date
    "value" : 100011 // number of documents
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: It seems fine. I want to achieve the same in a .js file.The output should be of the format                                              date1, count   date2,count   date3,count etc.

Comment: @prashantas What do you mean by `.js` file? Do you mean `node.js` script, or just a `.js` file executed in mongo shell?

Comment: It is just a .js file. Anyway I found the solution with your help.Thanks a lot.