# How do i get the count of entires for each date from a nested mongodb document?

Tags: php, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am a newbie in MONGODB.
I need to get the count of entries for each DEPLOYED date till today using MAPREDUCE function. i tired to look for answers but none matched according to my needs. Please Help !

I TRIED THIS BUT DIDNT WORK.
[How to get the count of records on each date in mongodb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407957/how-to-get-the-count-of-records-on-each-date-in-mongodb)

Even tired many others but still in  vain.

I am trying to write a php code for this one but even if u help me just by mongodb i can do the rest. Thanks in Advance.

P.s. - i read about getting date from _id and i tried it but still in vain.

My Mongodb Structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57e90143fe649e701e156e8d"),
"description" : "log_details",
"servicelog" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57e901436803fa2125f7b82a"),
        "name" : "Sam",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "telephone" : "1234567543",
        "pincode" : "1234",
        "servicetype" : "ambulance",
        "assigned_vehiclenumber" : "MH12AA0001",
        "Deploy_Timestamp" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-26 16:36:43",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Calcutta"
        },
        "Release_Timestamp" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-26 16:51:26",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Calcutta"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57e904cd6803fa2125f7b82b"),
        "name" : "Ram",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "telephone" : "6543134",
        "pincode" : "411011",
        "servicetype" : "ambulance",
        "assigned_vehiclenumber" : "MH12AA0001",
        "Deploy_Timestamp" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-26 16:51:49",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Calcutta"
        },
        "Release_Timestamp" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-26 17:00:19",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Calcutta"
        }
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("57e90e9a6803fa6879f7b82d"),
        "name" : "Atharva",
        "gender" : "Male",
        "telephone" : "12343143",
        "pincode" : "34532",
        "servicetype" : "ambulance",
        "assigned_vehiclenumber" : "MH12AA0001",
        "Deploy_Timestamp" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-26 17:33:38",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Calcutta"
        },
        "Release_Timestamp" : {
            "date" : "2016-09-26 18:28:39",
            "timezone_type" : 3,
            "timezone" : "Asia/Calcutta"
        }
    },
  .....
}
```